# Two rows in a menu with css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create header in a page, with a logo on the left side in the middle, and two like menus in 2 rows on the right side. How can I do it with css and using some classes from bootstrap? something like this

```
--------------------------------------------------|
          |    menu items 1 (aligned top-right)   |
Logo here |---------------------------------------|
          |    menu items 2 (aligned bottom-right)|
--------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: something like this, whatever i do, it is always pushing the items from its left side. this example is without a bootstrap, but its classes has the same functionality:
http://jsfiddle.net/4pjco6p3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-xs-4">
    // logo goes here
  </div>
  <div class="row col-xs-8">
    <div class="row col-xs-12">
      // upper part of menu
    </div>
    <div class="row col-xs-12">
      // lower part of menu
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good job Junaid, My only suggestion to this would be to use 'li' and span set to display block. that way he can control it better as a responsive menu ;)

Comment: You may be right. But by-default divs are display block. And on-the-other-hand I have solved lot of responsive issues using divs approach. Thanks for suggestions, I will try someday.